# Replace \224 in string

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I came accross this in some existing code. Hoping someone can tell me what this means- mostly what would \224 mean?

```
$line = str_replace('\224','"', $line)
```

Comment: Somebody wanted to replace all instances of the literal string `\224` with a double quote. That is not an escape sequence that has any meaning in PHP, and it is in single quotes so the backslash is literal anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It simply replaces the substring `\224` with `"`.  Nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a literal `'\224'` occurring in the string. Likely it is expecting that some sort of character code might be in `$line` that is coming out as `\224` and it's replacing it with the `"` character.

Answer (score 0):

in c++ you can reference any character by typing backslash followed by the ascii number for that character. and if that number starts with a lower case x, you can use hexadecimal numbers to reference it.

what happens if you do

```
<?php
    echo '\72\101\108\108\111\32\119\111\114\108\100<br />';
    echo "\72\101\108\108\111\32\119\111\114\108\100<br />";
    echo "test'\224'";
```